# How to dynamically hide/show field annotated with @ApiModelProperty in swagger?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, annotations, swagger

I want to show or hide field in object annotated with @ApiModelProperty depending on configuration property (if some functionality is enabled or not).

I have a class reading properties:

```
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my-properties")
@Validated
public class Properties{
 protected boolean propertyEnabled;
}
```

And second with my API:

```
@Data
@AllArgsArgument
public class MyRequest {
   @ApiModelProperty
   protected boolean field;
}
```

If property is enabled I want to show this "field" in swagger, but I want to hide it when property is set to false in config file.
I know there is 'hidden' argument in @ApiModelProperty, but I don't know how to make it configurable.

Comment: what is the relation between Properties and MyRequest?

Comment: Properties just reads configuration let's say from application.yml file -> I want to configure visibility of fields in MyRequest depending on this configuration. The purpose is to let someone to configure if he wants to have "field" or to hide it and disable functionality

Comment: ok but how are the two classes related? I mean, how can you access Properties.propertyEnabled from MyRequest?

Comment: Properties class can be autowired (@Autowired), but how is the main problem - I tried to write my own JsonDeserializer for MyRequest, I can there autowire properties and if necessary do not pass disabled field. But what I would like to achieve is that I don't want to see field in swagger if configuration is disabled, so I would have to set this "hidden" argument to true

Comment: There is no param on ApiModelProperty to achieve what you want and I don't think that you can disable a FIELD annotation based on conditions, you could disable a bean a whole bean using ConditionalOnProperty but I don't think that's your problem, @andziaa133 I would update the swagger doc to specify that the property is conditionally disabled, swagger is just documentation at the end

Comment: I could create two different models (with and without  "field") and create two methods in controller with annotation @ConditionalOnProperty (one on value true, one false). Can I do that without having ambiguous mapping exception (I want all parameters and request mapping the same) ?

Comment: That would require to have two methods on your controller mapped to the same endpoint witch is not possible, maybe changing the uri it could work but it seems kinda hardcore to me